# Error "could not retrieve certificate chain from keystore"

Tags: iphone, flash, adt

I'm currently working on packaging air application to iPhone with ADT (air 2.7).
i get the *key.p12* and *.mobileprovision* file in the IOS provisionning portal and I did this operation from a MacOS (keychain software).
When I run the adt command, I get the following error: "could not retrieve certificate chain from keystore".
I notice a curious thing in the Provisioning Portal. In Certificates section, the name which appears in the list is different than the name i have entered in keychain. For information, I have a professional account and not create by me.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

ok i answer myself cause i find an issue.

for some reasons, the p12 file created on MacOS didn’t work on Windows.
you can generate the key on windows with OpenSSL and thanks Adobe for documentation :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html#WSfffb011ac560372f284e44b012cd1e700c0-8000

Comment: This link describe only developer certificate generation. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes the link describe how to generate certificate on windows (if you don't have macOS & Keychain software)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to generate a new key.  See [Section Convert an Apple developer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html#WSfffb011ac560372f284e44b012cd1e700c0-8000) certificate to a P12 file on Windows and follow steps 1 and 2 then

Change this on step 3:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

to

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```